# Unique values of one column in a multiple column table in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, distinct

I want to create a new table with columns from another table. Only those rows should be selected, where column `x` has unique values. Column x should consist of the trimmed values of column `a`.

This is my code:

```
create table nodupli as 
    select distinct(regexp_replace(a,'[[:space:]]|[[:punct:]]','')) as x,
        B, 
        C, 
        D
    from table1
order by x;
```

How do I include only those rows with unique values in column x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join that query with another one that only returns the unique `x` values, like

```
select  x
from    table1
group by x
having count(*) = 1
```

The resulting query would be

```
create table nodupli as 
select  regexp_replace(t1.a,'[[:space:]]|[[:punct:]]','') as x,
        t1.B, 
        t1.C, 
        t1.D
from    table1 t1
join    (
            select  regexp_replace(a,'[[:space:]]|[[:punct:]]','') as x
            from    table1
            group by regexp_replace(a,'[[:space:]]|[[:punct:]]','')
            having count(*) = 1
        ) t2
on      regexp_replace(t1.a,'[[:space:]]|[[:punct:]]','') = t2.x
order by x;
```

**Edit**

The previous `join` condition was wrong because `x` is an alias given to the calculated column in the `select`, so it's somehow at "presentation-level". The actual column name is still the original one, and you need to use that in the `join` condition. I edited my query, which should now be correct.

Comment: Thank you. Shouldn't it be `from    table1 t1` inside the join brackets?

Comment: Thanks, I edited it. Having the same alias both in the inner query and in the outer one may be confusing, so I just removed the alias from `t1.a` in the inner one, because that's not necessary.

Comment: I tested the code with my data and get the error `00904. 00000 -  "G1"."X": invalid identifier"` on the line `on      g1.x = g2.x`. The x in in clob format. Is that the reason why it is not working?

Comment: I'm getting the error `00932. 00000 - "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"`, it expected - and got CLOB. Is the CLOB format incomparable? Is it even possible to join tables on a CLOB column? I'll ask a new question concerning the clob problem.